# Ruby constant returning nil when called in another class

Tags: ruby, class, oop, namespaces, constants

I have this class

```
class Foo
  MAIN_COMPUTER = @computer_name
  attr_accessor :computer_name

  def initialize
    @computer_name = "IComputer"
  end
end
```

When I try to access the MAIN_COMPUTER variable in another class' method, it returns nil even when an object of the Foo class has been initialized

```
class Gamer
  def opponent
    Foo::MAIN_COMPUTER
  end
end

me = Gamer.new
```

me.opponent returns nil. Is there a way to make Foo::MAIN_COMPUTER reference "IComputer" from the opponent method definition? Is there another way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

***edit 1***

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :computer_name

  def initialize
    @computer_name = "IComputer"
  end

  def self.main_computer
    @computer_name
  end
end

class Gamer
  def opponent
    Foo.main_computer
  end
end

me = Gamer.new
p me.opponent
```

last line of the code returns nil. Please could you explain this? Thank you

Comment: `Foo::MAIN_COMPUTER` is always `nil` here, it doesn't matter from where you call it. That's because `MAIN_COMPUTER = @computer_name` will just assign the _value_ from `@computer_name` (which is `nil` at that point) to the constant. It won't "link" the constant to the variable. Besides, the former `@computer_name` is a class instance variable whereas the latter (inside `initialize`) is a "normal" instance variable.

Comment: Can you explain what your code is supposed to achieve? It looks like you want the constant and the instance variable to have / share the same value. Why that redundancy? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The code I am working with is a bit more complex so I tried simplifying with the code I posted on here. Assuming I create a new Foo object, I am expecting Foo::MAIN_COMPUTER to reference "IComputer". is there a way to do this? Interesting what you said about class instance variables. I will do research on that

Comment: What if you create another `Foo` instance with a different `compurer_name` – is the constant supposed to change? Or should only the first instance set it? If so, what’s the value of `MAIN_COMPUTER` when no instance was created yet?

Comment: What are your thoughts about using the singleton pattern for this Foo class? https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/ruby/example

Comment: Yes it is supposed to change depending on what @computer_name is set to. Is there another way of getting Foo::MAIN_COMPUTER to reference "IComputer" from the Gamer class?

Comment: This seems like a code smell, constants aren’t supposed to change. Maybe a class method `Foo.main_computer` would be more appropriate. (or maybe a class method that returns the most recent instance)

Comment: "Is there another way to achieve this?" – There very likely are infinitely many other ways to achieve this, but it is impossible to tell without knowing what "this" is.

Comment: I want a way to make Foo::MAIN_COMPUTER reference "IComputer" from the Gamer class.

Comment: @Nnamdi: `Foo::MAIN_COMPUTER = "IComputer"` satisfies that. If that *doesn't* solve your problem, then you need to describe your problem better.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it seems like you want to have individual `Foo` instances and some "main" `Foo` instance that you can reference globally.

Constants aren't supposed to change (hence the name), so if you want that "main" object to be changeable, you should probably use a class method instead.

To add an attribute to the class itself:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :main_computer
  end

  attr_accessor :computer_name

  def initialize(computer_name)
    @computer_name = computer_name
  end
end
```

Calling `attr_accessor :main_computer` within `class << self` will create two methods: a getter `Foo.main_computer` and a setter `Foo.main_computer=`. The value will be stored in a *class instance variable* called `@main_computer` (i.e. right inside the class, not its instances).

Initially the value is `nil`:

```
Foo.main_computer
#=> nil
```

You can now create a new `Foo` instance and then assign it to `main_computer`:

```
foo = Foo.new("HAL 9000")
#=> #<Foo:0x00007f81321827d8 @computer_name="HAL 9000">

Foo.main_computer = foo
```

Which will allow you to reference that instance from another class:

```
Foo.main_computer
#=> #<Foo:0x00007f81321827d8 @computer_name="HAL 9000">
```

or, to get its name:

```
Foo.main_computer.computer_name
#=> "HAL 9000"
```

---

You can also make the `Foo` initializer assign itself to `main_computer`:

```
def initialize(computer_name)
  @computer_name = computer_name
  Foo.main_computer = self
end
```

to only assign if no `main_computer` is already present, use a conditional assignment:

```
def initialize(computer_name)
  @computer_name = computer_name
  Foo.main_computer ||= self
end
```